# Eclipse RCP export windows branding: icon (ico) only works with low resolutions

Tags: icons, eclipse-rcp, branding

I'm trying to brand my RCP application. For windows, I've created the following ico file:

http://data.icg.tugraz.at/caleydo/download/2.0.2/caleydo.ico

It contains all the resolutions the Eclipse export wizard requires, plus a couple of higher-resoultion versions.

However, when I look at the exported product in Windows, only the low-res versions of the icon are mine. When I look at higher resolution versions (e.g. the link on the desktop) my icon is replaced with the Eclipse icon.

When looking at the ico file in windows it scales as expected.

Is my icon incorrect, or can I do something else?

Comment: I've now found out that on other systems instead of the standard Eclipse icon only the low-resolution version of the icon is used.

I suspect that exchanging the ico file using a tool like http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/ will probably do the trick. However, I export the product on a regular basis and am looking for a process that does not involve manual post-processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've received an answer in the eclipse newsgroups:

Which version of Eclipse?  The high-res support only came in for Juno! And there are restrictions:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378662

Check your build logs as there may be errors during the icon branding.